# LoginAsync sometimes times out

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I have some authentication code for an Azure hosted mobile app that is being called from a WPF client. It attempts to authenticate the user as part of the initialisation of a Prism module that contains an authentication service. The async method to authenticate is written as follows:

```
public async Task AcquireTokenAndAuthenticateWebApiAsync()
{
    try
    {
        //todo these are hardcoded :-(  ... need to come from app settings!!

        // settings for authentication
        string resourceId = "https://windinspectordevmobileappservice.azurewebsites.net";
        //string resourceId = "http://localhost:51293/";

        string clientId = "5fe3b968-1d23-4667-9c31-86fac4ab4aec";
        Uri redirectUri = new Uri("https://windinspectordevmobileappservice.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done"); // Page to say you have sucessfully signed in
        const string appServiceUrl = "https://windinspectordevmobileappservice.azurewebsites.net";
        string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/dnv.onmicrosoft.com";


        this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);

        // authenticate against the AD
        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                resourceId, clientId, redirectUri,
                new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, false));

        this.authResult = result;


        // authenticate against the web api
        Client = new MobileServiceClient(appServiceUrl);
        JObject payload = new JObject();
        payload["access_token"] = authResult.AccessToken;

        var user = await Client.LoginAsync(
            MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,
            payload).ConfigureAwait(false);

        this.authenticatedUserName = this.authResult.UserInfo.DisplayableId;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {

    }
}
```

About 50% of the time the call to LoginAsync is successful. However, at other times the LoginAsync call simply times out (the task times out with an exception). What could cause this?

I've attempted to turn on the logs in the client, but see no reason for the timeout in the logs:

Application Log from Successful LoginAsync Call:

```
2017-01-27T16:24:29  PID[23292] Verbose     Received request: POST https://windinspectordevmobileappservice.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad

2017-01-27T16:24:29  PID[23292] Verbose     JWT validation succeeded. Subject: '__HeuajpWfXmUxZBrDvwAqcV0UOirMVrs5iCwvpnrrY', Issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/adf10e2b-b6e9-41d6-be2f-c12bb566019c/'.

2017-01-27T16:24:29  PID[23292] Information Login completed for 'max.palmer@dnvgl.com'. Provider: 'aad'.

2017-01-27T16:24:29  PID[23292] Information Sending response: 200.77 OK

2017-01-27 16:24:29 WINDINSPECTORDEVMOBILEAPPSERVICE POST /.auth/login/aad X-ARR-LOG-ID=4f08
```

---

Application Log from LoginAsync call that times out:

```
734a-75e2-4674-a9c8-bd74caa1aa3f 443 - 80.5.95.115 ZUMO/3.1+(lang=Managed;+os=Windows;+os_version=6.2.0.9200;+arch=Win32NT;+version=3.1.50105.0) - - windinspectordevmobileappservice.azurewebsites.net 200 77 0 1089 2739 109

2017-01-27T16:26:29  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).

2017-01-27T16:26:34  PID[23292] Verbose     Received request: POST https://windinspectordevmobileappservice.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad

2017-01-27T16:29:29  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
```

NB looking at these logs, when the login call is successful, I see "JWT validation succeeded", when it is not, I never see this line and it times out. I've checked many samples online for using this authentication pattern and the code looks good to me. I've also tried shifting the code to be called via an async command Execute method so that I'm async all the way (up).

Any thoughts on what else I can do to try to understand what might be the cause of the timeout in some cases?

One question I had is that the source code for MobileServiceClient is hosted at:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services

However, this repository is marked as deprecated (or at least Mobile Services is deprecated in favour of Mobile Apps). I presume this class is still the one to use with Mobile Apps?

Is there any way I can step into the code? Do I need to fetch the source from Git and debug that?

Comment: 50% seems kinda high; but you'll always have the possibility of a timeout and should code defensively to handle it.

Comment: Sure, that's something I will do. However, it's really common that it times out. I just don't know what's causing it - I can't identify a source of information that tells me what's timing out, other than the call to the LoginAsync method.

Comment: If they published symbols to symbolsource, then you could [try to use those](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio).

Comment: We publish symbols to symbolsource.  I don't know what is causing the timeout, as it doesn't look like the auth subsystem is actually responding - nothing to do with mobile apps (which is the SDK and isn't involved in auth).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to push down into the call stack.

Comment: Some others are looking at this now and have stepped into the code as you suggested, which has worked fine. It resolves down to a (http) call that times out. Interestingly they have reported that this low level call supports a cancellation token, but this is not exposed at the entry point, which would be useful. Our current best guess is that there is a potential issues with the AD provider.